# Why can the Application language be changed only once?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the app language in Java-Based Android.
This is the function:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

This function is from another question like "how to change the application language", **BUT IT WORKS ONLY ONCE** (for example from English to Hebrew).
**this is not a dublicate question**
Can you please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Change the language and set  languageValues to true  which is of boolean type.Now every time check languageValue when activity lunches.

Comment: @LeoPelozo this is not a duplicate, because the way I did it (like the answer of the question that you linked) worked but not on 100% of the application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your function with this one:

```
public void setLocale(String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale); // changes the languages
    Resources resources = getBaseContext().getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    this.recreate(); // re-launches the app
}
```